# jQuery Halt Form Submit

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, submit, halt

I've just put together a nice form which has taken me hours, with some natty jQuery focusout validation. The focusout attribute is attached to the input fields onload. I then re-use my validation functions by triggering the focusout event onsubmit, but what I don't know is how to disable the form submitting if any of my validation functions failed. Full example [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/PottyMonster/9YBqW/9/)

Cutdown example:

> addLoadEvent(AttachVal);
>
> function AttachVal(){
>
> ```
>   $('input[name="FirstName"]').focusout(NameTest);
>   $('input[name="LastName"]').focusout(NameTest);
>   $('form[name="Register"]').submit(SubmitRegForm);
> ```
>
> }
>
> function SubmitRegForm(){
>
> ```
>   $('input[name="FirstName"]').trigger('focusout');
>   $('input[name="LastName"]').trigger('focusout');
>   alert ("Submitting");
> ```
>
> return
>   false;
>   }

Validation function:

```
function NameTest(){

var result = true;          
var EnteredValue = $(this).val();
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;

    if (!(EnteredValue.match(alphaExp)))
    {
        var result = "Invalid"; 
    }   

    if (result !== true)
    {
        $(this).parent().next().children('span.ErrorDescript').text(result);
    }
    else
    {           
        $(this).parent().next().children('span.ErrorDescript').text("");        
    }
```

}

I tried attaching a variable in the SubmitRegForm function like this:

```
var FNStat = $('input[name="FirstName"]').trigger('focusout');
```

with the intention to check them all and submit if they all return true, but that just returns a object. Is it possible to get the response text from that function?...maybe? Or is there another way to force a halt of a Submit event that's currently running from within my individiual validation functions?

As always, any advice greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: why is a boolean changing to a string? should just set it false rather than "Invalid".

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery Validate? It'd save you a lot of code. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation, http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9YBqW/11/) What I did was in the return of the SubmitRegForm() method just see how many tick images are visible and if it's zero go ahead and submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to catch the form submission is like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    // Unfocus and validation logic here.
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` will stop the form from submitting.